# Google scripts and Alphavantage json query: TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: google-apps-script, alpha-vantage

I try to fetch data from AlphaVantage stock market API with this code:

```
function importjson (){     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("daily data");
   var day = new Date(),
      MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 *`enter code here` 24; 
   var urlvix = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=xlb&apikey=KEY",    responsevix = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlvix),
      jsonvix = JSON.parse(responsevix);
// var date = jsonvix["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];
   var yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(day.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      curdate  = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd");
   var open = jsonvix["Time Series (Daily)"][curdate]["5. adjusted close"],
        close = jsonvix["Time Series (Daily)"][curdate]["1. open"],
        volumetoday = jsonvix["Time Series (Daily)"][curdate]["6. volume"],
        volumeyesterday = jsonvix["Time Series (Daily)"][yesterday]["6. volume"];
 // Logger.log(date);
  Logger.log(curdate);
  Logger.log(yesterday);
  if  (volumetoday > (volumeyesterday + volumeyesterday*1.1) ){
  Logger.log("distribution");
  }
  else {
  Logger.log("keine distribution")
  };
  Logger.log("open: " + open);
  Logger.log("close: " + close);
  Logger.log("Today´s volume: " + volumetoday);
  Logger.log("Yesterday´s volume: " + volumeyesterday);
  }
```

Some times when i run the code i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "2018-09-13" from undefined. (Zeile 17, Datei "Libary")
```

or if i use `var date = jsonvix["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"];`

```
`TypeError: Cannot read property "["3. Last Refreshed"]" from undefined.` (Zeile 17, Datei "Libary")
```

The Json comes as this :

```
Meta Data   
1. Information  "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events"
2. Symbol   "MSFT"
3. Last Refreshed   "2018-09-13 13:37:27"
4. Output Size  "Compact"
5. Time Zone    "US/Eastern"
Time Series (Daily) 
2018-09-13  
1. open "112.1200"
2. high "113.7250"
3. low  "112.1200"
4. close    "112.8050"
5. adjusted close   "112.8050"
6. volume   "14261782"
7. dividend amount  "0.0000"
8. split coefficient    "1.0000"
```

The thing is ,i dont get the error everytime i run the code just sometimes, which makes it kinda unreliable.

Is there any mayor problem with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't always return the JSON you posted. Sometimes it returns:

```
{ 
"Information":
"Thank you for using Alpha Vantage! Please visit https://www.alphavantage.co/premium/ if you would like to have a higher API call volume."
}
```

As you can see, There's no `["Meta Data"]` or `["Time Series"]["2018-09-13"]` key here. The only key is `["Information"]`.

So, `jsonvix["Meta Data"]` will return `Undefined`, when you've exhausted your quota. You need to write code to make calls slowly and/or refetch after waiting a few seconds using `Utilities.sleep()` or opt for a higher volume with AlphaVantage.

#### References:

- [Usage Limits](https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#support)
- [Utilities.sleep](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))

Comment: I had a feeling the problem is related to the call limit, but i thought this code would only make 1 call. The limit for the api is 5 calls per minute. So that should not be a problem. Is it possible that the script is making numerous calls in some cases here?

Comment: @Hotzen It's possible that you ran the function frequently or the api is actually returning something else (Try ``Console.log(jsonvix)``). In addition, You posted your apikey in the public domain before -> Somebody else(or multiple others) might be using it too.